# Principles, Best Practices and Design Patterns for functional programming

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming, principles

Are there any known principles, best-practices and design patterns that one can follow while writing code in a functional programming language?

Answer (score 20):

There are folds, unfolds, maps, etc.

I consider using them best practice, as it is pretty easy to reason about their behavior, and they often communicate the purpose of a function (for an example, just take a look at the famous [Evolution of a Haskell Programmer](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html) and contrast freshman with senior, and with professor).

Answer (score 10):

Design pattern: **let types guide your coding**.

1. Figure out what type you are trying to return.
2. Know that certain type constructors come with certain syntax, and exploit it to make the desired type smaller.  Here are two examples:

   - If you are trying to return a function type `T1 -> T2`, it is *always* safe to write

     ```
     \ x -> ...
     ```

     Now in the body you are trying to produce a value of type `T2`, which is a smaller type, plus you have gained an extra value `x` of type `T1`, which may make your job easier.

     If the lambda turns out to be unnecessary, you can always eta-reduce it away later.
   - If you are trying to produce a pair of type `(T1, T2)`, you can always try to produce a value `x` of type `T1` and a value `y` of type `T2`, then form the pair `(x, y)`.  Again, you've reduced the problem to one with smaller types.
3. Once the types are as small as you can make them, look at the types of all the let-bound and lambda-bound variables in scope, and see how you can produce a value of the type you want.  Typically you expect to use all arguments to all functions; if you don't, be sure you can explain why.

In many situations, especially when writing polymorphic functions, this design technique can reduce the construction of a complicated function down to just one or two choices.  The types guide the construction of the program so that there are very few ways to write a function of the correct type---and usually only one way that is not obviously wrong.

Comment: This is what <a href="http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.38.9875">Theorems for Free</a> is about, right?

Comment: @Jared: I would say 'theorems for free' is more a source of algebraic laws that you can use when calculating with your programs.  Given the type of a polymorphic function there is a 'free theorem' which is an algebraic law that obeys.  I don't use these very often, whereas I do type-directed coding all the time.

Answer (score 9):

Best practice: use algebraic data types and take advantage of *exhaustiveness checking* from the pattern-match compiler.  In particular,

- Never match a wildcard pattern `_` at top level.
- Set compiler options so that a missing case in a pattern match is an error, not a warning.

Comment: You can use `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` combined with `-Werror` to get fatal errors when a case is missing. It can be also given on per-file basis using the [option pragma](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#options-pragma).

Answer (score 8):

Don't follow principles, follow your nose. Keep functions short. Look for ways to reduce the amount of complexity in code, which often but not necessarily means the most concise code. Learn how to use the builtin higher order functions.

Refactor and reduce the code size of a function right after you've written it. This saves time because tomorrow you won't already have the problem & solution in your mind.

Comment: DRY (DO not Repeat Yourself) can really help in reducing complexity. a single place to change is much easier than 2. 

Before you refactor, best you have your unit test cases, else might be a good time to start writing them.

Answer (score 4):

Design pattern: *let the compiler infer types* for your functions, and make sure those types are exactly as general as you expect.  If the types are more polymorphic or less polymorphic, figure out why.

For example, if you are writing a sort function in Haskell, expect

```
Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

If your type is

```
Num a => [a] -> [a]
```

or

```
[a] -> b
```

then something is horribly wrong.

Best practice: once you've confirmed with the compiler that the type is as you expect, *put an explicit type signature for every top-level function*.  (Or if you are using ML or Caml, write an explicit interface.)  Set compiler options so that values with missing signatures trigger an error.

Answer (score 3):

I'd answer with perhaps a bit vague principle: **strive to make your code beautiful** as the most important aspect. To [quote](http://quotes.cat-v.org/programming/) David Gelernter:

> Beauty is more important in computing than anywhere else in technology because software is so complicated. Beauty is the ultimate defence against complexity.

and Brian Kernighan:

> Controlling complexity is the essence of computer programming.

If you pursue this goal, it will lead you to write code that is **easy to read** and understand (which is very important), code that is split into small, compact parts with well defined purpose. It will lead you to learn how to express your thoughts in the best way in the particular language.

(All this doesn't apply just to functional languages, but writing beautiful code is so much easier in them.)

Answer (score 2):

[Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html) by John Hughes gives good motivation for why laziness and higher order (first class) functions provide a lot of what less functional languages are [missing and supplement with design patterns](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AreDesignPatternsMissingLanguageFeatures).

In the context of Haskell, I thought the book [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) had some good and practical advice about idioms and abstraction and type classes and the like. The [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/sitewiki/images/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf) is also always useful. The core, very abstract type classes could be looked at as design patterns except they are enforced by the compiler/type system and part of the language (if you learn how to use them).

In the context of Lisp, Paul Graham wrote a book called On Lisp ([available online](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html)) where he shows that functional languages are ideal to create a custom programming language and then write your program in that. So embedded domain specific languages themselves are a sort of design pattern.